# Click in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have such a button and I do not know how to press it. This is the button from the start of the video. I tried probably everything and it still does not work. Can I press it?

```
<button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button" aria-label="test"></button>
```

my code

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});         
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1749, height: 1080, deviceScaleFactor: 1, });
  await page.goto('https://www.bananki.pl/');
await page.waitFor(2000)
page.click("a[id='login-btn']")

await page.waitFor(2000)
await page.type('input[name=user_mail]', 'email', {delay: 20})
await page.type('input[name=user_pass]', 'password', {delay: 20})

await page.keyboard.press("Enter")

await page.waitFor(3000)
  await page.goto('https://www.bananki.pl/zdobywaj-bananki/banana-tv/');
await page.waitFor(5000)

await page.waitFor(10000);
})();
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: yes , now is all code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select it by doing

```
await page.click(<button css selector here>)
```

Comment: Additionally, you can wait for an element to appear by doing await page.waitForSelector(<your css selector>) so you dont have to wait for x milliseconds all the time

Comment: So everything that is in the button I'm looking for?

Comment: You can use chrome devtools to get the selector for the button. Go to the desired site, right click on the button then inspect element. Then in devtools you right click on the selected element and use the option copy > copy selector

Comment: I copied and pasted into the place where you said it and it shows you that you can't find the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
await page.click('.ytp-large-play-button[aria-label="test"]')
```

to be 100% sure that this will be this button.

Comment: Are you waiting for element before click?